# Two histograms on one one plot without overlap

Tags: r

I am trying to plot two sets of data on one histogram, but I dont want the bars to overlap, just to be next to each other in the same plot. currently I am using the code:

> plot(baxishist1,freq=FALSE, xlab = 'B-Axis (mm)', ylab = 'Percent of Sample', main = 'Distribution of B-Axis on Moraine 1', ylim=c(0,30),breaks=seq(25,60,1), col='blue')
>
> par(new=T)
>
> plot(baxishist2,freq=FALSE, xlab = 'B-Axis (mm)', ylab = 'Percent of Sample', main = 'Distribution of B-Axis on Moraine 2', ylim=c(0,30),breaks=seq(25,60,1), col='red')

and the results are [bars overlapping on histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ow4.png)

Can anyone help me to make the bars to be in the same bins but not overlap so that I can see both histograms?

Comment: Hello Jane, it would be a great help if you could reformat your question and provide a basic sample of data to help us help you better.
You can find every tips for this purpose here : [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would recommend *not* to keep the two histrograms in the same plot - no matter what visual tricks you use it will always be hard to read. I would plot two separate histograms forcing identical x-axes and show them in a column - much easier to interpret/compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a little easier to interpret, by using transparent colors.

Let's fist generate some data:

```
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100, mean=3)
```

And now plot the histograms:

```
hist(a, col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5))
hist(b, col=rgb(0,1,0,0.5), add=T)
```

[image]

As you can see, both are now somewhat visible but we would now have to manually adjust the x-axis to accomodate both distributions. And in any case, it's still not nice to read/interpret so I would rather plot two separate histograms, a boxplot or a violinplot.